# Why in Hinduism, God is only for high caste?

Tags: caste-system

As we know that Low caste people are not allowed to enter temple.

**Did Hindu God say only high caste can worship and low caste can not?**

Comment: if you are born in low caste, and if you have bhakti (devotion) to God, God will make high caste person carry you on his shoulder to see him

Comment: regarding temples, they have to be maintained very clean. even high caste people are not allowed to enter temples if they did not take bath, or if they did not wash their feet after going to toilet, or wash their hands after eating, or if they touch any person who is unclean due to above mentioned reasons. But nowadays nobody maintains these aachars, so everyone is equal

Comment: All castes people go to temple. It is about purity of the person who are entering. It is only in some rural areas where there is restriction of entering into temple. It has been almost abolished in rest of the country.

Comment: I never heard or see in my life any temple who don't allow low castes people to enter.

Comment: So far in my life, I haven't seen a single instance. Political propaganda, nothing else.

Comment: In Vishnu temples, everyone is allowed in the temple.In fact, I don't know of a temple in the country where lower castes are not allowed.

Comment: @ram if in our Shastras, restrictions are there on Low castes, then why are you saying- nowadays everyone is equal. "**Do not demean or reduce the ideal way just because ppl are unable to follow it nowadays.**"

Comment: @AnuragSingh, I clearly mentioned why everyone is equal in the sense that nobody follows cleanliness aacharas. In olden days, high caste people would maintain aachara and low caste people would not (because they need not according to shastras). So, in order to maintain cleanliness they were not allowed, and they themselves did not go, it's not like they wanted to go but were forcibly denied. Of course, those who had Bhakti, none could stop them.

Comment: @ram Then Abrahamic people are also as equal as Hindu people.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, I don't know why we are arguing. You can consider dogs also as 'equal' to Hindu people if u want. Among Hindus, there are some basic rules which most people follow - not going to temple without bathing, during menses, or janana/marana asoucha. Whereas Abrahamic people may not adhere to even these rules. And animals will probably pass waste inside temple, so they are even worse. There is a hierarchy of cleanliness.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, in olden days, this hierarchy was strictly maintained because people followed achara. But now, it has fallen to level of all castes (still within Hinduism, this is what I meant by equal, up to a threshold). Maybe in future, it will fall down to level of Abrahamic people and maybe even further later on.

Comment: @ram I meant my comment to point to your comment on not allowing an Abrahamic boy marrying a Hindu girl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59669/discussion-between-ram-and-anurag-singh).

Comment: @S.J.A I believe that there is no difference between Hindu god and other religion's god and castes have nothing to do with worship. God is for everyone. Everyone is equal.

Comment: i don't know what happened to the chat room, it's no longer accessible. and @AnuragSingh, you said that I believe that 'Smritis are no longer valid today'.. I never said that, in fact i vehemently argue against anyone who says that.

Comment: @ram Aghori AKA Rohit was saying so, that you also agree Smritis are not to be followed. He said he has had chat about this with you.

Comment: No. God has never said so. Bhagavaan Shiva says that even if a Chandaala wears Rudraaksha, he comes to My ShivaLoka. Devi Bhagawati has said that at all My Teerthas My devotee should see me in everything, be he a boy, girl or even a Chandaala. Devi had given Darshan to Samadhi Vaishya . All the SahasraNaama say that all Brahmin, Kshattriya, Vaishya and Shudra should recite the SahasraNaama.

Answer (score 7):

God is equally there for all people irrespective of caste, creed etc.

This has been explicitly declared in the Vedas as follows:

> PurutrA hi sadrngngasi visvo vishvA anu prabuhuh.
>
> ..............
>
> Thou art the lord **who looks with equal eyes on all the peoples in many
>   lands.**
>
> **Rig Veda 8.43.21**

So, just ignore all those people or institutions who/which say otherwise.

Comment: God is equal for all. But the question is about temples. If everyone was "equal", why not let everyone touch the archa-murthis in garbha-gruhas? Or why not give nuclear codes to everyone in a country? Or give everyone in a company the same salary? Concept of equality only makes sense if both responsiblity & reward are taken into account. If you are able and willing to take on a responsibility only then reward will be given. Even if you're high brahmin priest, you cannot enter temple premises if you're even little unclean (e.g. unwashed feet after eating), But nowadays, only few follow rules..

Comment: @ram Everyone who is clean internally and externally can touch idols.

Comment: **God is equal for all. But the question is about temples.** If Vedas say that God sees everyone equally then that would imply everyone irrespective of anything have equal right to access him and his abode. And temples are considered as God's abodes. @ram

Comment: if that was the case, everyone should have access to vaikunta. but that is not the case. @TheDestroyer, exactly, most 'low-caste' people don't care about cleanliness because shastras don't dictate them to be clean. and many 'high-caste' people also don't care about cleanliness even though shastras dictate them to be. Both of them are not eligible to touch idols

Comment: @ram I don't know about that. But I have seen many people touching Shiva Linga and even i touched it many times. Moreover, in Srisailam Jyotirlinga, there were no such rules and anyone was allowed to touch Shiva Linga even exterior unclean persons for some years.

Comment: @TheDestroyer People who think that that a unclean person can make the Shiva Lingam unclean by their touch have no idea about divinity.

Comment: @ram Yes that is indeed the case as the Veda mantra given in my answer explicitly suggests.

Comment: @Rickross Yes, like how fire doesn't get impurities, even Lord in idols doesn't become unclean if any unclean persons touch him.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, i don't about shiva lingas, but in vishnu temples, only bhattars (priests) can do aradhana for diety. none else is allowed to touch the deity. By your definition, since Lord is everywhere and is always touching everyone, nobody and nothing is unclean, and we can as well eat without brushing teeth, or eat food fallen on the ground.

Comment: @ram Why Shiva temples are exempted? It's simple and clear God won't get impurity if unclean human touches Him. It's absurd to say, Lord will become impure. I agree Purity is needed inside temple  or near Mula virat. But in physical manifestations (through Swayambhu Idols or other idols or Lingas), God won't get any impurity. God is present everywhere as Consciousness but our point of discussion is about manifestations as idols at certain places (Temples).

Comment: @TheDestroyer, like i said i don't know if touching shiva lingas is allowed by shastras, or if those temples where people touch are exceptions. any case, I agree that God will never be impure in the spiritual sense. But if anyone other than bhattars touches mula murthi in vishnu temples, they have to do kumbhabhishekam all over in order to regain sannidhyam (sanctity).

Comment: @ram Many Shiva temples allow us to touch Shiva Lingas, from Kasi to small temples. But i don't know why Vaishnava temples don't allow it.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, it is according to agama shastras. even at home, before touching salagrama, we have to do anganyasa/karanyasa to clean our body before touching. it is a mark of respect.